# Cypress - manually throwing error in a nested loop that does multiple checks

Tags: javascript, loops, testing, cypress

I need to test several dynamically created pages of a website; the aim is to check for every page if certain html blocks (each of one has an id, e.g. `<div id="test">...</div>` ) contains or not a list of words, which i saved and grouped in a `vocabulary.json` file.

What I did is a nested loop: first I loop over the "groups" of pages; then, for every group, I

- create an `it(...)` test
- inside this `it` test, I loop over each of the ids and I do several `expect` checks, using `.map()`, to check if that block contains or not several words. Those several checks are done by a function I created, that is tested and working.

Since if one of those checks fails, usually the tests will not continue, I managed to catch the errors thrown and return an array of `error.message` to the main function. Then, in the main function I check if this array is empty, and if it's not, I will `throw new Error(<array of errors>)` so Cypress will print those errors and mark as failed this test.

Here's what I did (code is strongly simplified to avoid wall of text):

```
// those urls are for pages of cities; urls.cities contains the name of the city,its url, and other
    urls.cities.forEach(elem => {
      it.only(`TEST for city ${elem.city} and job ${elem.job}`, () => {
        cy.visit(elem.url)

        // retrieve all the ids for the considered page
        let ids = retrieveIds(elem, 'cities')

        // if errors are present, they are all saved in an array
        let checkErrs = []

        // checkAllWebElementsOfCityUrl does all the 'expect' checks for the selected id
        // AND RETURNS AN ARRAY OF STRINGS, each of one is an error.message message; 
        // if no errors are thrown, it returns an empty array
        ids.forEach(id => {
          cy.get(id).then(webElem => {
            
            let res = checkAllWebElementsOfCityUrl(webElem, elem, id)

            if (res && res.length > 0) {
              console.log('PUSHED!')
              checkErrs.push(res)
            }
          })
        })

        // a wrap for checkErrs is needed because above function 'get' is async; all errors are flatten in one array
        cy.wrap(checkErrs).then(errsArr => {

          errsArr = errsArr.flat(Infinity)

          // if array contains at least one error, throw a new Error with a list of all errors (Error.message, a string) in the array)
          if (errsArr && errsArr.length) {
            throw new Error('Errors found!' + errsArr + '\n-end-')
          }
        })
      })
    })
```

This code actually works fine. My issue is that if several tests fails, the next passed test continues increasing execution times - numbers indicates failed tests - :

```
Retrieve all the auto-generated pages
  √ TEST for city new york and job no-one (9009ms)
  √ TEST for city dublin and job no-one (7008ms)
  √ TEST for city athens and job no-one (7663ms)
  √ TEST for city naples and job no-one (6757ms)
  √ TEST for city berlin and job no-one (6813ms)
  √ TEST for city paris and job no-one (7332ms)
  √ TEST for city atlanta and job no-one (6229ms)
  √ TEST for city bogota and job no-one (5209ms)
  √ TEST for city sidney and job no-one (6486ms)
  √ TEST for city minsk and job no-one (6150ms)
  √ TEST for city new york and job plumber (5113ms)
  √ TEST for city new york and job baker (6318ms)
  1) TEST for city new york and job butcher
  2) TEST for city new york and job influencer
  3) TEST for city new york and job computer technician
  4) TEST for city new york and job broker
  √ TEST for city new york and job street sweeper (18824ms)
  5) TEST for city new york and job driver
  √ TEST for city dublin and job plumber (19221ms)
  √ TEST for city dublin and job baker (24814ms)
  6) TEST for city dublin and job butcher
  7) TEST for city dublin and job influencer
  8) TEST for city dublin and job computer technician
  9) TEST for city dublin and job broker
  √ TEST for city dublin and job street sweeper (35455ms)
  [...several tests after...]
  30) TEST for city atlanta and job computer technician
  31) TEST for city atlanta and job driver
  √ TEST for city bogota and job plumber (100381ms)
```

I'm getting mad to understand why. The only thing I can say is that if I comment the line - only this line! -

```
throw new Error('Errors found!' + errsArr + '\n-end-')
```

the problem disappears. The tests are all markes as passed, because there's no thrown errors (inside `checkAllWebElementsOfCityUrl` I use

```
try {
  expect(webElement).to.contain(value)
} catch (error) {
  cy.log(error)
  errs.push(error.message)
}

[...]
return errs
```

Does anyone have any idea on WHY this happens?

### UPDATE

I totally rewrote the entire code but the error is still the same:

```
    it.only(`TEST for city ${elem.city} and job ${elem.job}`, () => {
    cy.visit(elem.url)

    let ids = retrieveIds(elem, 'cities')

    // if errors are present, they are all saved in an array
    let checkErrs = []

    cy.get(ids)
      .each((id) => {
        cy.get(id)
          .then((webElem) => {
            let res = checkAllWebElementsOfCityUrl(webElem, elem, id)
            if (res && res.length > 0) {
              checkErrs.push(res)
            }
          })
          .end()
      })
      .then(() => {
        checkErrs = checkErrs.flat(Infinity)
        console.log('checkErrs at the end of an id:', checkErrs)
        checkErrs = checkErrs.map((err) => {
          return '\n' + err
        })

        if (checkErrs && checkErrs.length) {
          throw new Error('Errors found!' + checkErrs + '\n-end-')
        }
      })
      .end()
  })
})
```